# Automatic Firefox Home Page Selection

Tags: firefox

So there are 2 web sites:

1. http://homesytem.lan/ and
2. http://www.google.com

Now, I want my browser to go to [1] and if [1] is not available then go to [2].

Another way to look at this is, if I am on home network I want to go to [1] else to [2].

The browser is Firefox.

How can this be done?

Comment: I'm happy with, home page going to a local html page with a bit of js to make the decision and redirection (if it is quick)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think, its possible in Firefox browser but you can set more than one website as a start-up page while you will run the Firefox browser, here in below I mention the steps, how to achieve it.

```
Open your Mozilla Firefox browser.
Then go to Tools >> Options >> General >> Home page.
So to set Multiple Homepages,
```

http://homesytem.lan/ | http://www.google.com

Paste the above code in Home page as URL.

Then Hit Home button on browser you will get two homepages open at same time.

You can set two or more than two homepages by modifying above code and putting ‘|’ symbol between two URLs.

Comment: Yes, firefox does not provide this by default. And I am looking for a seamless homepage which changes based on where I am connected. I don't want two tabs.